# fontconfig overriding normal weight and style of fonts

Tags: fontconfig

I want to override the weight or Normal style of a font. With the following config I can override the Regular weight/style to Medium but the Normal style (which also has the same weight as Regular) still remains fixed to Regular instead of Medium.

```xml
<fontconfig>
  <alias>
    <family>sans</family>
    <prefer><family>Roboto</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>

  <match target="pattern">
    <test name="style" qual="any" compare="eq"><string>normal</string></test>
    <edit name="style" mode="assign" binding="strong"><string>medium</string></edit>
  </match>

  <match target="pattern">
    <test name="weight" qual="any" compare="eq"><int>80</int></test>
    <edit name="weight" mode="assign" binding="strong"><int>100</int></edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

This is the result:

```
$ fc-match "Roboto: normal"
Roboto-Regular.ttf: "Roboto" "Regular"
$ fc-match "Roboto: regular"
Roboto-Medium.ttf: "Roboto" "Medium"
```

I wish to override the "normal" style with medium. Why doesn't this work and how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

the reason is, that `normal` is not a style/weight but a width definition.

```
[root@ArchTestVM ~]# fc-pattern "Roboto: normal"
Pattern has 2 elts (size 16)
        family: "Roboto"(s)
        width: 100(i)(s)
[root@ArchTestVM ~]# fc-pattern "Roboto: regular"
Pattern has 2 elts (size 16)
        family: "Roboto"(s)
        weight: 80(i)(s)
[root@ArchTestVM ~]# fc-pattern "Roboto: medium"
Pattern has 2 elts (size 16)
        family: "Roboto"(s)
        weight: 100(i)(s)
[root@ArchTestVM ~]# fc-pattern "Roboto: normal:medium"
Pattern has 3 elts (size 16)
        family: "Roboto"(s)
        weight: 100(i)(s)
        width: 100(i)(s)
```

The pattern "Roboto: normal" does not contain a definition for weight or family and thus maps to regular.
It is possible to match on width and change weight but this is possibly not what You want:

```
<match target="pattern">
    <test name="width" qual="any" compare="eq"><int>100</int></test>
    <edit name="weight" mode="assign" binding="strong"><int>100</int></edit>
</match>
<match target="pattern">
    <test name="weight" qual="any" compare="eq"><int>80</int></test>
    <edit name="weight" mode="assign" binding="strong"><int>100</int></edit>
</match>
```

```
[root@ArchTestVM ~]# fc-match "Roboto: normal"
SourceCodePro-Medium.otf: "Source Code Pro" "Medium"
[root@ArchTestVM ~]# fc-match "Roboto: normal:bold"
SourceCodePro-Medium.otf: "Source Code Pro" "Medium"
[root@ArchTestVM ~]# fc-pattern "Roboto: normal"
Pattern has 2 elts (size 16)
        family: "Roboto"(s)
        width: 100(i)(s)
[root@ArchTestVM ~]# fc-pattern "Roboto: normal:bold"
Pattern has 3 elts (size 16)
        family: "Roboto"(s)
        weight: 200(i)(s)
        width: 100(i)(s)
```

You would change bold to medium just because it defined width with 100.

Or are You searching for a way to change default weight if no weight in pattern defined to 100?

---

Edit. Even explicitly specified as weight instead of width it is not working:

```
[root@ArchTestVM ~]# fc-match "Roboto: weight=normal"
Fontconfig error: Unexpected constant name `normal' used for object `weight': should be `width'
Unable to parse the pattern
```

This makes sense as there is regular for weight 80 but no other word for width 100 and it is fine that the keywords can be distinguished. Just the question why they allow the 'normal' alias to 'regular' in `<const>` tags according to docs.

Comment: Yes I want to change the default weight to Medium. If I don't specify the style then fc-match reports Regular by default. This is what I was looking to change.

Comment: Second looking at the fontconfig documentation, there appear to be two definitions for normal. One is the width and the other is the weight.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html

Comment: Yes it's documented to be a valid value in the const element like an alias for regular width. But it doesn't seem to be a valid keyword nowadays for font pattern, it's even forbidden if You explicitly say You want it for the weight instead of the width it's complaining (try `Roboto: weight=normal` which would declare it's usage explicitly).  So You see it's not allowed to be used as alias there. (Probably they should remove it from the docs or mark it as it's not easy to find the documentation for the allowed pattern values,,)